# Start Android App in a specific tab

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

The question is: I have a `TabHost` with 4 tabs (see code below) and I got a `Button` in `MainMenuActivity` class. The `Button` is set up with a `OnClickListener` and if it is clicked I want it to go to the second tab. I have tried with `setCurrentTab(1)` but that just messed the project up. What can I do?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTabs() ; 
}
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, MainMenuActivity.class);
    addTab("Calculate", R.drawable.tab_search, SpinnerClass.class);

    addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_home, ScrollView1.class);
    addTab("Premium", R.drawable.tab_search, ScrollView2.class);

}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(index)` is the right way to go. What's the problem when you use it?

*"setCurrentTab(int) opens the tab to be displayed by default, specified by the index position of the tab."*

Comment: hey,i have a question. i have horizontal scrollview in which i have my tabhost.tabHost.setCurrentTab(index) sets the current tab but the scrollview has to set to scroll to the current tab which is not working.could you please help me??