# How to Show Second Tab in Android while calling from an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the Code which I'm Trying. How to go to `Tab2` from `Sample`? Please help me to Solve this.

```
public class DemoTab extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_and_login_tab);
        setTabs() ;
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("Tab1", R.drawable.tab_search, Tab1.class);
        addTab("Tab2", R.drawable.tab_home, Tab2.class);        
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

}
```

Code for Tab2

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
    }


}
```

Code for Tab1

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button check;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
        check= (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        check.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.check:
            //Do the Task Search Here
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sample.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Code for Sample

```
public class Sample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button redirect;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_result);
        redirect= (Button)findViewById(R.id.redirect);
        redirect.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.redirect:
```

**Here What should i do to get view of Tab2,By default the DemoTab's Current Tab will be Tab1.**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DemoTab.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: just try like this...  TabHost tab = getTabHost();
  TabSpec tab1 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb1");
  TabSpec tab2 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb2");
  tab1.setIndicator("Export").setContent(
    new Intent(this, Oderorinvoice.class));
  tab2.setIndicator("Back Up").setContent(
    new Intent(this, Oderorinvoice2.class));

  tab.addTab(tab1);
  tab.addTab(tab2);

Comment: To achieve this you can use actionbarsherlock library. Here is the link that describe solution to your problem:  http://blog.eilfa.com/actionbarsherlock-with-fragments/

Comment: This code is a working code. But I'm not getting TabActivity view thats the problem

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper That's not the problem. I want to call the Tabactiviy that i created from other activity which is not belongs to this. And i want to show Tab2 as currentTab when i'm calling from other activity only Otherwise the default should be Tab1

Comment: If i try Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DemoTab.class); startActivity(i); Then it's showing Tab1 but Here in this specific code how can i redirect to Tab2 that's what i need. And By default DemoTab's Current Tab will be Tab1.

Comment: @Aadi can u try the edited answer?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Thanks I think that's the only way to achieve this task. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try like this...

when call the tabactivity call like this

```
 Intent go=new Intent(this,TabActivity.class);
 Bundle b=new Bundle();
 b.putString("condition","tab2");
 go.putExtras(b);
 startActivity(go);
```

then in tabAcitivity class

```
public class Demo extends TabActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    String con=b.getString("condition");

    TabHost tab = getTabHost();
    TabSpec tab1 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb1");
    TabSpec tab2 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb2");
    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Tab1.class));
    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Tab2.class));

    tab.addTab(tab1);
    tab.addTab(tab2);
   if(con.equals("tab2")
     {
     tab.setCurrentTab(1);
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setCurrentTab(index)` opens the tab to be displayed by default, specified by the index position of the tab. If you set `tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);` property while creating your TabActivity, it will show the tab on 1st index as you desire( 0 will set it to a tab on 0th index). You might want to check some of the above questions as well:

[android setting default tab in tab-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541538/android-setting-default-tab-in-tab-activity)

[Start Android App in a specific tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507160/start-android-app-in-a-specific-tab?rq=1)

[setCurrentTab of a tabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425742/setcurrenttab-of-a-tabhost)

**Edit**

[Android TabHost setCurrentTab()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912003/android-tabhost-setcurrenttab)

```
public class DemoTab extends TabActivity {
    //Declare this outside the elements
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        // ...
        addTab("Tab1", R.drawable.tab_search, Tab1.class);
        addTab("Tab2", R.drawable.tab_home, Tab2.class);  
        // Here you may try adding
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);    
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        tabHost = getTabHost(); v//edit this line
        //....
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Aadi Chek the updated answer. After you define tabs, you might want to set the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Classes "One.Java" and "Two.Java". My main Activity which is extends 'TabActivity'. In onCreate() method :

```
Intent one = new Intent(this, One.class);
Intent two = new Intent(this, Two.class);

TabHost t = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
t.setup();

TabSpec tspecOne = t.newTabSpec("CLICK ONE").setIndicator("CLICK ONE")
            .setContent(one);
t.addTab(tspecOne);

TabSpec tspecTwo = t.newTabSpec("CLICK TWO")
            .setIndicator("CLICK TWO").setContent(two);
t.addTab(tspecTwo);
```

Comment: Add the code `tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);` after `tabHost.addTab(spec);`